# python how to use getattr on a class

Tags: python, class, module, getattr

I have a simple use case, I have a class:

```
class A:
  def meth1(self, name):
    ...
  def meth2(self, name, funcname):
    # funcname is a string 'meth1'
    # how do I invoke meth1 by using funcname string here self.funcname(name)?
```

I tried using getattr, but was not sure how to go about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
def meth2(self, name, funcname):
    getattr(self, funcname)(name)
```

since [`getattr(self, 'meth1')`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#getattr) is equivalent to `self.meth1`.

Comment: ah! i was thinking maybe we should use modules[self] to get class context and then invoke getattr on it. thanks!

Comment: The key principle here is that Python sports [First-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) - which means functions are just regular objects, and you can get a reference to them without calling them (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Could pass the funcname as a parameter to the getattr function and invoke it with the parameter name.

```
def meth1(self, name):
    print name

def meth2(self, name, funcname):
    getattr(self, funcname)(name)
```

That would print the value name passed to meth2 via meth1.